# OnClick function radio not working

Tags: jquery

I am calling function onclick radio button but its working on only one radio button not on other as well. How can I call the same function on both radio buttons ?

```
$("#trip_type_filter").change(function(){           
if($(this).val()=="yes")
  {
    $('[class="single_trip"]').show();
    $('[class="multi_trip"]').show();
    $('[class="all_inclusive_single"]').show();
    $('[class="all_inclusive_multi"]').show();
    $('[class="trip_cancellation"]').show();
  } 
else if($(this).val()=="no")
  {
    $('[class="single_trip"]').show();
    $('[class="multi_trip"]').hide();
    $('[class="all_inclusive_single"]').hide();
    $('[class="all_inclusive_multi"]').hide();
    $('[class="trip_cancellation"]').hide();
  }
});
```

Here is html:

```
<input type="radio" id="trip_type_filter" name="trip_type_filter" value="yes" /> Yes
<input type="radio" id="trip_type_filter" name="trip_type_filter" value="no" /> No
```

AND

```
<div class="single_trip">single_trip</div>
<div class="multi_trip">multi_trip</div>
<div class="all_inclusive_single">all_inclusive_single</div>
<div class="all_inclusive_multi">all_inclusive_multi</div>
<div class="trip_cancellation">trip_cancellation</div>
```

Comment: IDs **must be unique** in your HTML document. You are recycling the ID `trip_type_filter`. Since the browser only expects one element, it will often pick the first occurrence and bind the change event to it, ignoring the remaining occurrences.

Comment: any alternative please ?

Answer (score 1):

Both ids are the same. Use different ids. Also add a class to your checkboxes and add the event to the class:

*HTML*

```
<input type="radio" id="trip_type_filter" class="checkChange" name="trip_type_filter" value="yes" /> Yes
<input type="radio" id="trip_type_filter2" class="checkChange" name="trip_type_filter" value="no" /> No
```

*Javascript*

```
$(".checkChange").change(function(){           
if($(this).val()=="yes")
  {
    $('[class="single_trip"]').show();
    $('[class="multi_trip"]').show();
    $('[class="all_inclusive_single"]').show();
    $('[class="all_inclusive_multi"]').show();
    $('[class="trip_cancellation"]').show();
  } 
else if($(this).val()=="no")
  {
    $('[class="single_trip"]').show();
    $('[class="multi_trip"]').hide();
    $('[class="all_inclusive_single"]').hide();
    $('[class="all_inclusive_multi"]').hide();
    $('[class="trip_cancellation"]').hide();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
$("#trip_type_filter").change(function(){
```

To

```
$("input[type=radio][name=trip_type_filter]").change(function(){
```

Answer (score 0):

change your inputs ids. and check with class.

```
<input type="radio" id="trip_type_filter_yes" class="classToCheck" name="trip_type_filter" value="yes" /> Yes
<input type="radio" id="trip_type_filter_no" class="classToCheck" name="trip_type_filter" value="no" /> No
```

and use class chere

```
$(".classToCheck").change
```

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it correct. I just changed your checkbox ids into classes, and the change event to respond to changes in that class:

```
<input type="radio" class="trip_type_filter" name="trip_type_filter" value="yes" />Yes
<input type="radio" class="trip_type_filter" name="trip_type_filter" value="no" />No
```

```js
$(".trip_type_filter").change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "yes") {
        $('[class="single_trip"]').show();
        $('[class="multi_trip"]').show();
        $('[class="all_inclusive_single"]').show();
        $('[class="all_inclusive_multi"]').show();
        $('[class="trip_cancellation"]').show();
    } else if ($(this).val() == "no") {
        $('[class="single_trip"]').show();
        $('[class="multi_trip"]').hide();
        $('[class="all_inclusive_single"]').hide();
        $('[class="all_inclusive_multi"]').hide();
        $('[class="trip_cancellation"]').hide();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" class="trip_type_filter" name="trip_type_filter" value="yes" />Yes
<input type="radio" class="trip_type_filter" name="trip_type_filter" value="no" />No
<div class="single_trip">single_trip</div>
<div class="multi_trip">multi_trip</div>
<div class="all_inclusive_single">all_inclusive_single</div>
<div class="all_inclusive_multi">all_inclusive_multi</div>
<div class="trip_cancellation">trip_cancellation</div>
```